# How can notes be both tied and staccato?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

So, a tweet included this image.

[image: musical score with incidental face]

https://twitter.com/sognandoy/status/797952576830328832

This appears to be declaring that these two chords are tied together (legato) and distinctly separate (staccato). How would this be played?

Comment: With a smile on your face?

Comment: This looks like keyboard music, and unless you have more tentacles than an octopus, you can't play the notes any other way but detached. Really, this sort of marking is more decorative than useful - especially since it's in parentheses. Also, the twitter link is meaningless for non-Japanese readers!

Answer (score 2):

This (I believe) is usually used for string instruments, where the intention is that the notes are played staccato, but together on the same bowstring.  I don't think it is used much these days though.

On piano, I think the idea is to imitate the string sound in a [portato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portato) fashion

Comment: [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portato) adds the following recipe for keyboard: release the keys between the notes, as with staccato, but press more firmly and longer than with staccato.